# Trying to scrape all of the titles of a Soundcloud user's likes into a text file with the API

Tags: soundcloud

I can print the title of an individual link if the link is given, but is there any functionality in the API that would allow me to print each song name of a user's repost and likes one by one into a text file?

Answer (score 1):

The API exposes an interface to get a user's likes (the `/favorites` endpoint).  The saving to a file part is API agnostic, you'll have to write a program to parse the contents of the API call and write it to a file.  You haven't specified a language, so here's a small Swift script I wrote to to save a user's liked tracks to a text file:

```
let userId = "10032807" // User you want to get the likes from
let clientId = "[API KEY]" // your API key

guard let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/\(userId)/favorites?client_id=\(clientId)") else {
    fatalError("bad URL")
}


NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    do {

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        if let likes = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as? [[String : AnyObject]] {

            var likedTracks = [String]()

            for track: [String : AnyObject] in likes {
                if let title = track["title"] as? String {
                    likedTracks.append(title)
                }
            }

            let output = likedTracks.joinWithSeparator("\n")

            do {
                try output.writeToFile("Users/jal/tracks.txt", atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Error writing to file: \(error)")
            }
        }



    } catch {
        fatalError("Error with web request: \(error)")
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: Do you think you can show me something similar in Java?

Comment: @Laugh7 sure.  Update your question with your work-in-progress Java implementation and I'll try to guide you from where you're stuck.

Comment: Actually I think I want to make this an online application. Should I use ruby on rails for this? I have wanted to learn ruby on rails or Python w/ Django which do you suggest?

Comment: @Laugh7 I'm really not sure, it's all preference.  I mostly do mobile dev and wouldn't have a great answer to which tech stack you should chose.